# How to search json field value in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to search for the key "Gift".

```
"name": {"en": "Gift", "bn": "গিফট" },
```

I am trying this-

```
 "name": { [Op.and]: [{ 'en': text }]}
```

but not work. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
}


const map =  {"en": "Gift", "bn": "গিফট" };
console.log(getKeyByValue(map,"Gift"));
```